# Does the Google Tag Manager (GTM) process online identifiers / cookie identifiers?

Tags: google-tag-manager

The [Google Ads Data Protection Terms](https://privacy.google.com/businesses/adsservices/) are saying that Google Tag Manager processes

> Online identifiers, including cookie identifiers and internet protocol addresses

While IP adresses makes sense, how does GTM process "Online identifiers, including cookie identifiers"? As far as I can tell, an empty Tag Manager container doesn't set any cookies or other identifiers, or does it?

I fully understand that loads of cookies are set, once I use the GTM to place tags for Google Analytics or Google Ads. But just by itself?

Comment: GTM can read 1st party cookies, even if they were not set via GTM (it doesn't do that by default, though). Also it uses 3rd party cookies for the preview mode. My guess is that this is just in case that future GTM versions will use cookies somehow.

Comment: Hadn't thought about the preview mode - makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, here's more on GTM being able to read 1st party cookies: https://www.analyticsmania.com/other-posts/does-google-tag-manager-use-cookies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments below the question:

GTM does indeed generally not set cookies, with the exception of the preview mode. That aside, GTM can *read* cookies, as explained over here: https://www.analyticsmania.com/other-posts/does-google-tag-manager-use-cookies/